# Relative imports on next app created with nx using VS Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js, nrwl-nx

I'm facing an issue with a Next.js project bootstraped with [nx](https://nx.dev/) and VS Code:

When I try to auto-import a component using VS Code, it will generate an absolute import which immediately triggers the `@nrwl/nx/enforce-module-boundaries` eslint rule, making the current file invalid.

For example, with folder structure:

```
apps/my-app/
  pages/
    entity/
      new/
        index.tsx
  components/
    Loading.tsx
```

The generated import will be:

```
// in my-app/pages/entity/new/index.tsx
import Loading from 'apps/my-app/components/Loading'
```

While I expect:

```
import Loading from '../../../components/Loading'
```

VS Code has a setting to always use relative paths for imports, but that will prevent me from importing libraries in the proper way (`@scope/lib`).

Is there any possible setup that can make auto imports work as expected?

Comment: VS codes auto import setting usually figures out what's a library and leaves it as a bare specifier. Sometimes it gets very confused though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure the `paths` property in the `tsconfig.base.json` file at the root of your project. If you add it to other tsconfig files it will not work, the correct one is the `tsconfig.base.json` file at the root of your project.

Going off of your example, you can add the following to the `paths` option.

```
"@my-app/*": ["apps/my-app/*"]
```

Now you can change `../../../components/Loading` to `@my-app/components/Loading`.

More detailed example (note: I've erased a bunch of the other options that should be in your `tsconfig.base.json` file for readability)

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "@my-app/*": [
                "apps/my-app/*"
            ]
        }
}
```

Source and more info in the official TS Handbook: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work if overriding the paths of tsconfig in libs or apps folder, I thought the baseUrl still should be the root folder. Although I can add the path aliases in tsconfig.base, but I got `Projects should use relative imports to import from other files within the same project. Use "./path/to/file" instead of import from` eslint error

Comment: This will trigger the `nx` eslint rule as the other comment suggests. At the moment there doesn't seem to be a healthy workaroud for this other than using `baseUrl: '.'` in the `tsconfig.spec.json` and duplicating the paths in the base tsconfig

Comment: @Chi Was your lint error fixed? If so, how?

Comment: use lint --fix it should automatically replace to relative paths after you setup correct paths for typescript

Answer (score 4):

For those who are coming here without this getting resolved. (nx monorepo usage)

Trouble shooting the 2 errors (TS error and lint error):

First the Alias error:
`Cannot find module '@account/components/something' or its corresponding type declarations.`

1. On your base tsconfig.base.json (not tsconfig.json under your apps as it gets overrided), add:

```
 "compilerOptions":{
       ...
       baseUrl:"." // Try "src" as well incase of boiler plates or if your resolved path (on the error) is missing an src.
       path: {
       "@account/*": ["app/*"],
       "@account/components/*": ["app/components/*"] 
     }
   },
```

The above will resolve:

`import { authMiddleware } from '@account/components/something';`

from

`import { authMiddleware } from '../../../components/something';`

For lint error:
 Projects should use relative imports to import from other files within the same project - eslint rule @nrwl/nx/enforce-module-boundaries fails`

1. Add "allowCircularSelfDependency": true.

```
        "@nrwl/nx/enforce-module-boundaries": [
          "error",
          {
            "allowCircularSelfDependency": true, -> This may solve the lint error.
            "allow": ["@account/**"], -> // White list the lint error.
             ...
          }
```

2. Whitelist the folders: Add "allow": [@foldername]

```
        "@nrwl/nx/enforce-module-boundaries": [
          "error",
          {
            
            "allow": ["@account/**"], -> // White list the lint error.
             ...
           }
```

That should fix it.

Comment: both of these methods worked for me but can you specify why they work?